# Fields of object is random when returned

Tags: c++

I have a class Node that amongst other things, contain the fields

```
class Node{
public:
    int lowestCost;
    std::list<Node> children;

    Node* leastCost();
    Node();
    Node(int low)
}
Node(int low){
  this->lowestCost = low;
}
```

And a function

```
Node* Node::leastCost() {

    if(children.empty()){
        //this works fine
        return this;
    }
    else{
      //This doesn't
      Node* lowboi = (&children.front());
        for(Node n : children) {
            if ((*lowboi).lowestCost > n.lowestCost) {
                    lowboi= (&n);
            }
        }
        return (*lowboi).leastCost();
    }
}
```

When i try to acces a field of a node* being returned by the function like

```
Node* startNode = new Node();
current = startNode;

current.children.emplace_back(Node(1));
current.children.emplace_back(Node(1));
current.children.emplace_back(Node(3));
current.children.emplace_back(Node(4));

`This is just an example`

current = (*startNode).leastCost();



cout<<(*current).children.size();
```

The count is some large number like 4363000057, while it can be at most 4

Comment: What does `count()` return? Where is whatever it returns initialized?

Comment: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: My bad, it's ".size()"

Comment: [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) says "Calling front on an empty container is undefined." I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but you should move the `Node* lowboi = (&children.front());` into the `else` to avoid any UB.

Comment: This should be a minimal reproducible example
If i print the size of the children list before leastCost returns, it says 4. If i do it on the output of the function 'node.leastCost().children.size()' it returns 4363000057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop creates a copy of your nodes on the stack:

```
    for(Node n : children) {
        if ((*lowboi).lowestCost > n.lowestCost) {
                lowboi= (&n);
        }
    }
```

Your `lowboi` variable therefore becomes a dangling pointer at the end of the loop iteration. If you make `n` a reference this should solve the problem (assuming the list nodes themselves remain valid for the lifetime of the pointer):

```
    for(Node& n : children) {
        if ((*lowboi).lowestCost > n.lowestCost) {
                lowboi= (&n);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tick. Alternatively, toss the loop entirely and run a `std::min_element` across the sequence with a proper comparator provided via lambda. As a bonus, the name itself reflect what is actually going on, making intent clear. Such library algorithms are provided precisely to avoid making mistakes in presumably simple logic (which we can see can easily happen).